# What does it mean when two groups commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

This is probably an easy question, but I can't find the definition in my book.

Let $G$ be a group, and let $H$ and $N$ be subgroups. What does it mean for $H$ and $N$ to commute?

I have two possibilities that come to mind:

1. $(\forall h \in H)(\forall n \in N)[hn=nh]$
2. $HN=NH$, that is, if we have $hn$, then there exists $h_2,n_2$ such that $hn=n_2h_2$
   .

What is the correct definition?

I have this problem because of this exercise:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of $G$.
>
> a) Show that if either $A$ or $B$ is normal, then $AB=\{ab \mid a\in A, b \in B\}$ is a subgroup. Show by an example that the assumption $A$ or $B$ be normal can not be dropped.
>
> Show that if $A$ and $B$ **commute**, then $N =\{(x,x^{-1}) \mid x \in A \cap B\}$ is a normal subgroup of the direct product $A \times B$ and that AB is isomorphic to $A\times B /N$.

Comment: Probably the former. If its in the context of $H,N$ being normal subgroups whose intersection is only the identity, then it is the former.

Comment: More likely $hg=gh$ and $ng=gn$ for $g\in G$, $h\in H$ and $n\in N$. Is there a theorem or consequence of this concept in the book that would help verify the definition? E.g., "If $H$ and $N$ are in $G$ and they both commute, then..."

Comment: @ToddWilcox I updated the context of the question.

Comment: Probably the second one. If the author means the latter and hasn't defined it, I regard this as a pretty severe slip-up.

Comment: Now I agree with the second possibility also.

Comment: But it may also be like you said, and none of the two possibilities I wrote. Maybe when he says that A and B commute, it can be said like this: A commutes, and B commutes, so that in that respect A and B have nothing to do with each other?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

By definition $$HK := \{hk ; h \in H \, \, \text{and}\,\, k \in K\}$$

Naturally, if $y \in KH$ and $KH = HK$ then it means that on one hand $y = hk$, for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ and can be written as $y = k'h'$, for some $k'\in K$ and $h' \in H$ not necessarily implying that $h' = h$ and $k' = k$.

Consider the following result.

**Proposition 1:** Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Then $$HK \leq G \iff HK = KH \tag {*}$$

And (*) is meant by commute.

**Proof:**

$(\implies)$ Let $a \in KH$. There exists $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ such that $a = kh$. We have that $a^{-1} = (kh)^{-1} = h^{-1}k^{-1} \in HK$. As $HK \leq G$ then $a \in HK$ then $KH \subseteq HK$. Conversely, take $c \in HK$. We know that $HK$ is subgroup then $c^{-1} \in HK$ thus $c^{-1} = h_2 k_2$, where $h_2 \in H$ and $k_2 \in K$, taking the inverses we have $c = k_2^{-1}h^{-1}_2 \in KH$. Thus $HK= KH$.

Do you think you can take the other direction?

(a) Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. If $H$ or $K$ is normal in $G$ then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**Proof:** (idea)

Say $H \triangleleft G$ and $K$ is any subgroup of $G$. Show that $HK= KH$ and use **Proposition 1**. Again a case of two inclusions to be shown.

As to the example, take $\langle ab \rangle , \langle b\rangle \leq S_3$ and notice that $\langle ab \rangle  \langle b\rangle = \{id, a, b, ab\}$ has order $4$.